# Aligning Floated Elements with images and texts

Tags: css, css-float

So I'm working on a layout http://www.reversl.net/colors/ that should look like http://www.reversl.net/demo/ but I've run into two small problems.

1) I cannot get the avatar to align with the bottom of the text next to it. (I've tried adding vertical-align: bottom to the img tag but to no avail)

2) I cannot get the the stats to align evenly with the avatar. There should be a way to do this by just floating rather than having to add a negative margin to the stats right?

Answer (score 0):

You should put both of those into a div and float them left and right if you want them aligned that way. Here is what I would change in the CSS.

```
.card {
  display:block;
}
.op {
  margin-top: 1em;
  float:left;
}
.meta li:after {
  content:"";
  clear:both;
  display:inline-block;
  width:1px;
  height:1px;
}
```

and the put those into their own div

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="op">
       <a href="#"><img src="avatar.png" alt="" />Josh</a>
  </div><!--.op-->
  <ul class="meta">
       <li class="fav">
            <a href="#" title="See fans of this screenshot">304</a>
        </li>
        <li class="cmnt
            ">
            <a href="#" title="View comments on this screenshot">35</a>
        </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

The clear-fix with `:after` will make it so the parent doesn't collapse behind it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="op">
<a href="#">
<img alt="" src="avatar.png">
Josh
</a>
</div>
<div class="meta">
<div class="fav">
<a title="See fans of this screenshot" href="#">304</a>
</div>
<div class="cmnt ">
<a title="View comments on this screenshot" href="#">35</a>
</div>
</div>
```

This should be ur css

```
.meta{
position:relative;
width:50%; // u  can set the width to ur preference
float:right;
height:auto;
}
.cmnt , fav {
float:left;
}
.op {
height: auto;
float:left;
margin-top: 1em;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 50%;
}
```

havnt tested it,but hoping it should work..

Comment: Vivek and @wesleyterry Thanks. I got both options to work for aligning the avatar with the name but I could get either solution to work for the meta links